# Meaning of each field in default Format of HTTP Request Log in DropWizard

Tags: http, jersey, dropwizard

The access log that get generated in Dropwizard are something of following format:-

10.10.10.10 -  -  [16/Mar/2015:23:59:59 +0530] "GET /yyyy/vx.x/uri HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "-"  1

Field 1 :- 10.10.10.10 (Ip Address from which request came)

Field 2 :- [16/Mar/2015:23:59:59 +0530] (Time and Date when request came)

Field 3 :- "GET /yyyy/vx.x/uri HTTP/1.1" (HTTP Rest API method)

Field 4 :- 200 (HTTP Response code)

Field 5 :- "-" (????)

Field 6 :- "-" (????)
Field 7 :- 1 (????)

Can someone explain the meaning of each field in access log format? I am more curious about the last column meaning.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This logging is actually generated by Jetty and is an extended version of the [NCSA common log format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format). You can view the [source (search for the `log` method)](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractNCSARequestLog.java).

The default settings log the following:

- The remote server address
- Optional authentication information
- Request date and time
- The HTTP method, URI, and protocol for the request
- The HTTP response status code
- The length of the response
- The HTTP referer header (if set)
- The HTTP user agent (if set)
- The log latency

The last field (which you asked about in particular) is the latency in milliseconds between the time of the request and the construction of the log message - effectively how long it took the server to handle the request.

Comment: Adding some more info, if someone wants to add explicit pattern to server logs then specify following dropwizard properties---- server:
  requestLog:
    type: classic
    appenders:
      - logFormat: 'combined'
        target: stdout
        threshold: ALL
        timeZone: UTC
        type: console ref: https://logback.qos.ch/access.html