# Drop wizard request log format

Tags: logging, logback, dropwizard

We are using drop wizard 0.6 version and see below format in the logs.
My logging configuration has the following.
Not sure which logging format it is using.
Trying to find the field names for last 2 fields(**5 5**) of the log.
Can someone help please help me on this?

file:
      enabled: 'true'
      currentLogFilename: logs/access.log
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: logs/access.log.%d.gz
      archivedFileCount: '5'

127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2020:00:21:01 +0000] "GET /metrics/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1000 5 5

Update:
I tried using this format,but still prints similar as above.
Not sure from where it pulls the config.

logFormat: 'combined'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of each field in default Format of HTTP Request Log in DropWizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098340/meaning-of-each-field-in-default-format-of-http-request-log-in-dropwizard)

Comment: In my case it is priniting twice,so wanted to find out where is the config coming from.Let me know.